# Collecting all links in the main page and sub-pages

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I am trying make a script collect all links in main and sub-pages

For example, I need to collect example.com, example.com/link1, example.com/link1/sub-link1, ...

Please check my code

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Instantiate webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open Chrome maximized
driver.maximize_window()

# Open a link
driver.get("https://www.calculator.net/")

links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

header = ['URL', 'Name']

with open('/home/user/calculator.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)

  # write the header
  writer.writerow(header)

  for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    data = [href, link.text]
    # write the data
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Please note that I tried to add `driver.get(href)` to the for loop, but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try with `BeautifulSoup` module and let driver sleep a little.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
driver.get("https://www.calculator.net/")
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
driver.close()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
links = bs.find_all('a')
for link in links:
   print(link.attrs['href']
```